# Xcode 11.3 Universal Framework Issue

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xcframework, ios-universal-framework

How to Create **Custom** **Universal Framework** in **Xcode 11.3** and **iOS 13**, Any run script?

Comment: I follow this link --** https://medium.com/allatoneplace/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a?**

Comment: Hi Praveen, I think you should check this out: https://github.com/gurhub/universal-framework Best.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Add new Target from Cross-platform->Aggregate

Step 2:
From build phrases add following as run script:

## Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.

FRAMEWORK_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_BCSYMBOLMAP_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos"

DEVICE_DSYM_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework.dSYM"

SIMULATOR_DSYM_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework.dSYM"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

OUTPUT_DIR="./Build-Framework"

DRPBOX_DIR="/Users/$USER/Dropbox/Frameworks/iTelMessagingKit"

## This builds your framework for the target simulator.

Xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.Xcodeproj -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -scheme ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean install CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator

## This builds your framework for the device.

Xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.Xcodeproj -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -scheme ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean install CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos

## Let’s clean up the final directories:

## rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"

rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

## Now, we take one of the framework files to our universal folder:

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"

## Now for the real magic, lipo, add this snippet:

lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo
cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"

## cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$DRPBOX_DIR"